# sftp connection too many publickey verification attempts were made error

Tags: linux, sftp, private-key, openssh

I'm trying to do a sftp connection. The destination uses public key + password authentication, and port 2222.

I was able to connect from our existing linux host to the destination. Our existing linux host uses Openssh_5.3.

```
sftp -v -oPort=2222 -oIdentityFile=/home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa user@sftp.abc.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key ...
...
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Here it goes to the next authentication method keyboard-interactive with no problem.
```

I'm not able to connect from our next linux host. It uses OpenSSH_6.6.1. Our new linux host has same outbound IP and the destination is not filtering connection by IP address. I'm using the exactly same private key file and sftp command. So it seems like an ssh issue?

The error I got is:

```
sftp -v -oPort=2222 -oIdentityFile=/home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa user@sftp.abc.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ....
......
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ....
......
Here it goes as infinite loop and keep trying the same private key again and again (although it already got partial success)
until it got "**Too many publickey verification attempts were made**" error.
```

If I run with -vvv, here's the output:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 7f:69:c6:c9:be:54:6e:7a:35:7d:63:b6:7f:28:0f:20
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 7f:69:c6:c9:be:54:6e:7a:35:7d:63:b6:7f:28:0f:20
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 7f:69:c6:c9:be:54:6e:7a:35:7d:63:b6:7f:28:0f:20
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xyz/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xyz/.ssh/abc/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 7f:69:c6:c9:be:54:6e:7a:35:7d:63:b6:7f:28:0f:20
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

This goes on again and again, so I just killed it.
```

Comment: Are the private keys really the same?  Can you compare a hash of them to be sure?

Comment: Yes they're the same. They're the same file under my home directory. The home directory files are shared across different hosts

Comment: I'll create a thread on Unix & Linux, but I'm not able to do that now. I need to wait for 40min to do another post.

Comment: Post the whole log. you might exclude something what is important.

Comment: I added some more log